# ¿Que expresión regular me permite varios espacios en blanco y el caracter #

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy buscando una expresión regular que me permita usar letras minúsculas, mayúsculas, números del 0 al 9 pero que también me permita usar espacios en blanco y solo permita usar # y -

```
var exp4 = /^[a-zA-Z áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ]*$/;
```

Tengo esta expresión que me permite hacer lo anterior adicional deja pasar los acentos, pero no he encontrado una que me permita lo otro.

Una manita por fa!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

según las reglas que comentaste, como no hablaste de máximo de posiciones y orden, creo que esta te serviría.

```
/^[ a-zA-Z0-9á-úÁ-Ú#ñÑ-]*$/
```

Espero ser de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Amigo no sirvio :( intente ingresar un valor asi: calle 3 # 4-46 y no sirvio

Comment: Hola, debería funcionar, quizás te faltó agregar el inicio y fin que tenías originalmente y que yo omití.
Así:

`/^[ a-zA-Z0-9á-úÁ-Ú#-ñÑ]*$/`

Comment: no tampoco así ni siquiera con una dirección mas simple como manzana 4 casa 3

Comment: Ya encontré el problema jajaja por leer rápido me falto el espacio al inicio de la expresión. Gracias

Comment: Espera, igualmente es posible que esté mal, creo que cometí un error y quizás cualquier signo lo interprete como válido a menos que lo dejes así : /^[ a-zA-Z0-9á-úÁ-Ú#ñÑ-]*$/ (Ya edité la respuesta)